# RSA Algorithm: Invalid plaintext when performing decryption

Tags: java, cryptography, bigdecimal

```
class Calculate
{
  double gcd(double a, double b)
  {
    if (b == 0)
    {
      return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }

  Calculate()
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter values of p : ");
    double p = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nEnter value of q : ");
    double q = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nEnter Message: ");
    double m = sc.nextDouble();  // message

    double n = p * q;
    System.out.println("n = " + n);    // first part of the public key
    double phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    System.out.println("phi = " + phi);

    // assuming e = 3 
    double e = 3;        // second part of the public key

    // e must be relatively prime and smaller than phi
    while (e < phi)
    {
      if (gcd(e, phi) == 1)
      {
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        e++;
      }
    }

    // to find d
    // method : (k * phi + 1) / e = quotient should be 0 ( perfectly divisible)
    double k = 1;
    double d;
    while (true)
    {
      double temp = 1 + (k * phi);
      if (temp % e == 0)
      {
        d = temp / e;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        k++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("d = " + d);

    // encryption
    double c = 0;  // cypher text
    double x = Math.pow(m, e);
    c = x % n;
    System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + c);

    // decryption
    BigDecimal pt;      // plain text
    double y = Math.pow(c, d);
    BigDecimal Y = BigDecimal.valueOf(y);
    BigDecimal N = BigDecimal.valueOf(n);
    pt = Y.remainder(N);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + pt);
  }
}
```

p = 11

q = 5

m = 9

Calculating by hand gives the values:

n = 55

phi = 40

d = 27

Encrypted Text = 14.0

These are correct values.

But I am getting wrong value for the decryption even though the formula is correct.

Decrypted Text = 25.0 // Wrong value. It should be 9.

First I figured double is not enough to represent the large values while calculating plain text.

So I used BigDecimal (I am new to this)

The formula to calculate decrypted text is correct. I don't understand what is wrong with the program.

Comment: Not sure what wrong yet, but you may want to work completely with BigInteger (no double). You may want to print intermediate results

Comment: `double x = Math.pow(m, e);`. Modular exponentiation cannot be performed by doing the modular reduction afterwards. This is because integers overflow and doubles lose precision. Furthermore, in real world scenarios, performing exponentiation without reduction step on really big numbers will not be efficient. As gusto2 has indicated: use `BigInteger` and check the correct method to be used. You won't be surprised after this text that a special method has been implemented specifically for this.

Comment: I see. Thank your gusto2 and Maarten Bodewes.

Comment: Print out intermediate values and comment out the user input part. Use fixed constant values instead. **Don't use doubles!**. Use integers and BigIntegers only. No doubles, no BigDecimals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to do .mod(N) instead of .remainder().

```
// decryption
BigInteger N = BigDecimal.valueOf(n).toBigInteger();
//converting double value of c to BigInteger
BigInteger C = BigDecimal.valueOf(c).toBigInteger();
int dint = (int) Math.round(d);
BigInteger msgback = (C.pow(dint)).mod(N);
System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + msgback);
```

This is a slightly modified version, I converted the double d to an integer, so pow can be called. Good luck!

Comment: remainder() does the same job and it's used because BigDecimal is used. Thank you for answer. I understood what the problem is as gusto2 and Maarten suggested.